# Altium Designer - Drag a component and all traces attached to it

Tags: altium

In the PCB editor, I am trying to move a component and also the traces that it is connected to. I tried using the Drag command but the component still becomes disconnected from the traces.

Comment: Select the traces as well as the component and then use the Edit->Move->Selection command (E-M-S) to move the group

Comment: When I move the component and trace, it disconnects the other end of the trace from what I want it connected to. Is there a way to move a component while having the trace adapt to the change, without disconnecting the other side of the trace from my other components? Hopefully this isn't too vague.

Comment: No, part of your job as a PCB designer is to ROUTE. Not just move things around and rely on the software to do it for you.

Comment: Ok, sometimes I shift a bunch of components over a smidge to fit another part. I dislike the tedious task of having to reroute each trace to connect to the components new location when it is just a few mils away.

Comment: That is why you do component placement before you route. That's standard PCB design practice. The from-tos show where your tracks need to connect and give you an idea of where you need to position components

Comment: I have keepout zones around some of my components, so it is difficult to see if they overlap with my traces until I actually place the traces.

Comment: Your other option is to group the components by function block off the board and route them off the board, then bring everything into the board to route the different blocks together

Comment: @DerStrom8 Part of your job as a computer programmer is to WRITE machine code. Not just write functions and rely on the compiler to do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible in Altium Designer 19. Watch the below video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfML_NWr2sI

Comment: Was this feature always there? The video came out two years after I asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

Edit>Move>Drag Track End works best for me (Altium 18.1.7), and after a bit of use I actually like it pretty well.  I found that solution in another thread with many more options to try to get the traces to move with the component. Try a search for the phrase "rubber band traces altium".  I know this is an older thread--hopefully you found an answer to your question before now--but I figure if I'm reading this now then someone else might benefit too.  Happy routing!

Answer (score 0):

Altium is not good at dragging a part while also keeping the tracks from crossing each other. I came from Orcad which did as you desire. I was very surprised that Altium did not do it, since I thought of it as a basic concept. The best you can do in Altium is to slice the tracks that are attached to the part, un-route the component, drag it to its new location, then re-route the tracks manually or auto-route the component.