# In Altium do trace routes not move along with components?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Do trace route lines not move along with components? For example, I moved the resistor in the image and the traces dont move along with it.

I am new to Altium from Eagle and in Eagle when you move a component the traces drag along too. Is there some setting to turn this on?

[image]

Comment: Some EDA tools distinguish a component move (what you're seeing) from a component drag, which pulls the traces along with it.  I don't use Altium, so I can't comment on what it does, or how to make it drag instead of just move.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/328104/altium-designer-drag-a-component-and-all-traces-attached-to-it

Answer (score 2):

See Altium [documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-cmd-moveobjectmoveobject-ad), **Move Component**. This will only work if **Comp Drag** is set up in your preferences (Tools->Preferences->PCB Editor->General->Other->Comp Drag = Connected Tracks).

I generally don't like dragging tracks when I move a component as it creates a mess unless it's a simple move. Thus, the default behaviour is desirable for me.

First, set up preferences.

[image: Pref]

To drag tracks when moving component you can click your way in to the move component command (Edit->Move->Component) as shown in the following image, or issue the command with keyboard command **EMC**:

[image: move]

Comment: Agree, usually you're much better off moving your component and then redrawing the traces.